# Install puppetmaster on Sles 12 SP 2

Tags: linux, puppet, opensuse, suse, sles

Hello I want to install puppet (puppetmaster) on a SLES 12 SP 2 VM, but I can't find any documentation or instructions.

I already tried :

- [Install Puppet on OpenSuse 11.4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBITFtHI8_U)
- [Install Puppet on SLES 11 SP3](https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/docs/wiki/Building-Puppet)

Have any one a good instructions for me. 
It would help me a lot, cause i am already misspent several days for it.

Comment: Enterprise or not?

Comment: I want it to install on Suse Linux Server Enterpreise 12 SP2
- Yes Enterprise

Comment: Matt probably meant whether you're trying to install [Puppet Enterprise](https://puppet.com/product) or the community version.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers NO , SLES is enterprise distribution and 'comunity or enterprise puppet' isnt here seupported and you will lost support if you install packages from third source

Comment: Because your organizational constraints apply to everyone, right? Funny how Puppetlabs even provides an official SLES 12 package when nobody is using it ...

Answer (score 1):

`puppet` is part of "**Advanced Systems Management Module**" --> see https://www.suse.com/products/server/features/modules.html

so , you need enable it in **`yast2 registration`** and all other is same as in SLE11SP4 -> **`zypper in puppet`** and Puppet official documentation

Comment: Thank for the answer. I will try it the next time and will give you a response.

Comment: @StefanKuppelwieser vote up is enough :) And mark answer as valid :)

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppetserver/latest/install_from_packages.html#suse-linux-enterprise-server).

> ### Quick Start
>
> 1. [Enable the Puppet package repositories](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/puppet_platform.html), if you haven’t already done so.
>
> […]
>
> 3. Install the Puppet Server package by running:
>
>    ```
>    yum install puppetserver
>    ```
>
>    […]
>
>    Note that there is no - in the package name.
>
> […]
>
> 4. Start the Puppet Server service:
>
>    ```
>    systemctl start puppetserver
>    ```
>
>    Or
>
>    ```
>    service puppetserver start
>    ```

> ### Using Puppet 6 Platform
>
> […]
>
> ### Yum-based systems
>
> To enable the Puppet 6 Platform repository:
>
> 1. Choose the package based on your operating system and version. The packages are located in the `puppet6` directory of the [yum.puppet.com](https://yum.puppetlabs.com/) repository and named using the following convention:
>
>    ```
>    <PLATFORM_NAME>-release-<OS ABBREVIATION>-<OS VERSION>.noarch.rpm
>    ```
>
>    For instance, the package for Puppet 6 Platform on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (RHEL 7) is `puppet6-release-el-7.noarch.rpm`.
> 2. Use the `rpm` tool as root with the upgrade (`-U`) flag, and optionally the verbose (`-v`), and hash (`-h`) flags:
>
> […]
>
> SuSE Enterprise Linux 12
>
> ```
> sudo rpm -Uvh https://yum.puppet.com/puppet6/puppet6-release-sles-12.noarch.rpm
> ```

Comment: yum on sles ? seriously ? + Unsupported release on Enterprise system? Nice way how to lost supportability

Comment: @mimi.vx Thanks for the downvote. You may want to take those questions to Puppetlabs, though, since I was quoting their official documentation (now updated).

Comment: @mimi.vx BTW, someone who's [apparently still shipping Puppet 3](https://forums.suse.com/showthread.php?11627-Timeline-for-Puppet-4-Server-in-Repository) (which [reached EOL almost 2 years ago](https://rnelson0.com/2016/10/25/puppet-3-end-of-life-12312016/)) has no business talking about "unsupported releases". At all. HAND.

Comment: support dont need to be from upstream. SUSE and Redhat are paid for supporting old codebases. This is why Enterprise distributions exist.

Comment: @mimi.vx *"support dont need to be from upstream."* You may want to think about that for a minute (particularly in light of your reasoning for your downvote). Cognitive dissonance much?